# Sort NSarray based on integer value stored in the array of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I have Nssarray named Cameralist; in that I have collection of camerainfo class objects.

```
[ cameraInfoObject1 , cameraInfoObject2, cameraInfoObject3 , ...etc]
```

There is one property for each camerInfo object i.e cameraindex which is integer.

Therefore it is cameraInfoObject1.Cameraindex.

Hence I want to sort my cameralist array based on the camera index which is property present in every cameraInfoObject inside cameralist object.

Currently I am using this

```
 NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor      sortDescriptorWithKey:@"camerainfo.cameraindex" ascending:YES selector:@selector(intValue)];
    [self.service.gMyCameraList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

but my app crashes as soon as the control reaches this point.

Comment: Will you please at least take the time to capitalize your sentences and use proper formatting, when you're expecting others to read your stuff and help you?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Your sort descriptor key should just be cameraindex

Comment: Voting to close this question as unclear - it was abandoned without supplying a stacktrace as requested.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [self.service.gMyCameraList sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(CameraInfo a, CameraInfo b) {
  if ( a.Cameraindex < b.Cameraindex) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if ( a.Cameraindex > b.Cameraindex) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } 
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Assuming that your objects are CameraInfo type, if not, just change that name.